# How to use structured data for video list pages?

Tags: seo, structured-data, video, markup

I have a video sharing website.
How can i use structured data for the pages that contain list of videos?

I read google guideline about list of items:
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/product

Google say : **you can use markup for multiple items but you should use markup for each item in your list page**.

But I don't know about Video type.How about video list?
Is it same as product list rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply structured data according to the **[Google guide for the list](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-listings)**.

Note that there are two alternatives for markup:

> There are two ways to implement a list format for your structured data:
>
> - Summary page + multiple full details pages
> - A single, all-in-one-page list

Comment: Thanks.The link say "List format is currently supported for the following content types. This list is growing, so feel free to create a list for other types as they become supported: Recipe, Film, Course, Article, Recipe.".So video is not in supported types.Can I use video type? And also can you tell me about a page for a video and related videos?

Comment: Refer to the guide of Google of Video https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/video

Comment: I edited your answer but rejected.Your answer needs this link about multiple items in page and related videos:
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies#multiple-elements-on-a-page

A category page listing several different videos.Each entity should be marked up .If one item is marked, all items should be marked. Also, unless this is a carousel page, the marked items should not link out to separate details pages.

A video play page with related videos embedded in a separate section on the page. In this case, mark up the main video and related videos individually.

Comment: Try to provide a link to the web page. It is very difficult to recommend structured data abstractly, because they must represent the main content of the web page.